# I want to write a XML sheet in MATLAB and I want to add a number to the tag

Tags: xml, matlab

I have read a XML sheet into the MATLAB and I want to add a number to each tag(number) automatically depending on the number in the for loop.

`for i=1:tmp
    fileName = docNode.createElement(sprintf('ESM_ID'+'%d',i));
    fileName.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(files(i)));
    docRootNode.appendChild(fileName);
    end`

So above I try to add a number to the tag but it throws  an error:

```
Error using SMERCGUI>pushbutton1_Callback (line 613)
Error using plus
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
    feval(varargin{:});

 Error in SMERCGUI (line 44)
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)SMERCGUI('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Answer (score 1):

So, There was a syntax error. It should add value to the tag depending upon the for loop value the variable holds at that moment.

```
for i=1:tmp fileName = docNode.createElement(sprintf('ESM_ID_%d',i)); 
fileName.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(files(i)));
docRootNode.appendChild(fileName);
end
```

Thank You. My Bad- dint check with the syntax but it would be useful for someone else.